# Digital Business Card using QRcode

Tags: reactjs

Hi Can someone help me how to create a digital business card by scanning the generated QRcode using React JS.. I have created a form where the user fills in the details like name, email, mobile number etc and when they click sumbit it should generate a QRcode, once the user scans that code from their mobile device or any device its should open a digital card..

The QR code which i generated is showing no usable data found when i scan from my phone,  and I don't know how to show the digital card in their device if the user scans the QR code

```
const QRCodePage = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  if (!state) {
    return <div>No data found</div>;
  }
  const { firstName, lastName, company, designation } = state;
  const qrData = `Name: ${firstName} ${lastName}\n Company: ${company}\nDesignation: ${designation}`;
console.log("Name:",`${firstName} ${lastName}`)
console.log("Company:",company)
console.log("Designation:",designation)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Here's your QR code:</h1>
      <QRCode value={qrData} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default QRCodePage;
```